# Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase for analytics and push notification.

I am getting push notification on my device but analytics are not showing in firebase console.In logcat on studio it shows "Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService".

When I am trying to using below commands from event status

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

I am getting below response from terminal

```
Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 730280
08-04 12:30:51.751 V/FA-SVC  ( 4287): Background event processing time, ms: 26
08-04 12:30:56.686 V/FA      (19359): Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

Please suggest what will be the possible error/mistakes.

Comment: That logging message seems fairly benign. What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: same issue in my project

Answer (score -1):

I believe this message is expected. You may need to wait several hours before first data shows up in the console. Double check your integration (your secrets, the `google-services.json` file and if it's being loaded by the plugin, etc) to make sure you haven't made a mistake somewhere else.